# Calculating score by counting and subtracting foreign key instances in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a class Summary:

```
class Summary(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    content = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    users_rated_positive = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, blank=True, related_name='summaries_rated_positive')
    users_rated_negative = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, blank=True, related_name='summaries_rated_negative')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='summaries_authored')
```

and a class UserProfile:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, related_name='profile')
    karma = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    rank = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
```

I want the karma to be calculated as the positive ratings on all the users summaries minus the negative ratings on all the users summaries

I figured I could add a property like this instead of a field:

```
@property
def karma(self):
summaries_list = self.user.summaries_authored.all()
positive_karma = sum(
    [summary.users_rated_positive.count() for summary in summaries_list])
negative_karma = sum(
    [summary.users_rated_negative.count() for summary in summaries_list])
return positive_karma - negative_karma
```

Is this the right way to do this? I feel like I should be using aggregate, or annotate but to be honest I'm new to Django and not entirely sure how they work for complex situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count  

positive_karma = Summary.objects.filter(author=self.user).aggregate(pos_count=Count('users_rated_positive'))['pos_count']

negative_karma = Summary.objects.filter(author=self.user).aggregate(neg_count=Count('users_rated_negative'))['neg_count']
```

`aggregate` returns a dict so the actual value must be retrieved by the key

You would use `annotate` if you wanted to get the count of pos/neg ratings for every user.

Comment: I'm trying to count the amount of ratings for the summaries that a paticular user has authored, not sure this is that